# How do you read FULL address using coreLocation ( iOS/ Swift )

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-location

Here's the code:

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(myCurrentLoc) { (array, err) in

        print(err)
        if err != nil {
            print(err) 
            return
        }

        if let place = array?.first {

            if let locality = place.locality {
                if let country = place.country {
                    if let addr = place.addressDictionary {
                        print(addr)
                    }
                    let myAddress = "\(locality) \(country)"
                    self.adress.text = myAddress
                    self.locMgr.stopUpdatingLocation()

                }
            }

        }
        self.locMgr.stopUpdatingLocation()

    }
```

So I can read longitude/latitude, and the only thing I need is the full address. Right now I can print out "New York, US", I find all the information I need is in place.addressDictionary, which is a dictionary. But I can't seem to read anything from that dictionary using normal syntax. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually make a location manager helper to fetch details and use a placemark

The dictionary you are talking about comes with `placemarks`

Here is my Model

```
class UserLocation: NSObject {

 var latitude : String?
 var longitude: String?
 var timeZone: String?
 var city : String?
 var state : String?
 var country : String?
 // you can and more fields of placemark

required init(latitude:String?,longitude:String?,timezone:String?,city:String?,state:String?,country:String?) {
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
    self.timeZone = timezone
    self.city = city
    self.state = state
    self.country = country
   }


}
```

And then I use the below code to reverse geocode after getting a location from Location Manager and use `placemarks` to get details

```
//Location Manager delegate
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        if placemarks!.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks![0]
            if let location = manager.location {
                let userLoc = UserLocation(latitude: String(location.coordinate.latitude), longitude: String(location.coordinate.longitude), timezone: NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().name, city: pm.locality!, state: pm.administrativeArea!, country:pm.country!)

                //By printing this dictionary you will get the complete address
                print(pm.addressDictionary)

                print(userLoc.city!)
                print(userLoc.state!)
                print(userLoc.country!)
                print(userLoc.latitude!)
                print(userLoc.longitude!)
                print(userLoc.timeZone!)

            } else {
                //Handle error
            }
            if(!CLGeocoder().geocoding){
                CLGeocoder().cancelGeocode()
            }
        }else{
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
}
```

Also you can fetch other properties of placemark like

[image]

[image]

I also printed the addressDictionary and you can see the complete address in the console in the last image

Answer (score 1):

For US address you can use this:

```
let address = [
                place.name, 
                place.locality,
                place.administrativeArea,
                place.postalCode, 
                place.country
]

let formattedAddress = address.flatMap({ $0 }).joined(separator: ", ")
```

`Address` is an array of components that are used to compose typical postal address. It can contain nil for some items.

`FormattedAddress` removes the nils and adds delimiter, I used coma here.

Comment: value of type [String] has no member of "joined"

Comment: @FateRiddle it does in Swift 3. If you use older, there is `joinWithSeparator`